# Can you get the key path to a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

It was suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5867) that a good way to generate unique, deterministic values for a component (such as for an HTML id) would be from the key path. However, there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to get or compute this path. Is this possible without using private APIs, or am I out of luck?

Context: I have an application for editing reports. Depending on external factors, various sub-editors will be available. Each sub-editor will dispatch events to change the “real” data, which is of fixed structure. In addition, various sub-editors may have their own UI state. Because I can't predict what UI state will exist on the page, the structure of the total UI state will vary. However, I would like to save, log, and replay changes to the UI state for user research, so it will all go through the Redux store. Because this data is only used for UI purposes, I don't care where it's kept in the store, as long as it's kept somewhere deterministic.

Example of what this could look like:

```
const MyEditorComponent = connect(
    state => ({
        editors: state.config.subEditors,
        uiState: state.uiState
    })
)(({ data, uiState, dispatch }) => {
    const uiKey = this.getKeyPath() + '/currentEditor';
    const currentEditor = uiState[uiKey];

    return (
        <Selector value={currentEditor} onChange={value => dispatch( MyActions.setUiState(uiKey, value) )}>
            {editors.map( ({ id, title }) => <div key={id} selectorValue={id}>{title}</div> )}
        </Selector>

        <TabbedView value={currentEditor}>
            {editors.map( ({ id, type }) => <type key={id} tabbedViewId={id} /> )}
        </TabbedView>
    );
});
```